# Automating WebTrends analysis

Tags: automation, screen-scraping, webtrends

Every week I access server logs processed by WebTrends (for about 7 profiles) and copy ad clickthrough and visitor information into Excel spreadsheets. A lot of it is just accessing certain sections and finding the right title and then copying the unique visitor information.

I tried using WebTrends' built-in query tool but that is really poorly done (only uses a drag-and-drop system instead of text-based) and it has a maximum number of parameters and maximum length of queries to query with. As far as I know, the tools in WebTrends are not suitable to my purpose of automating the entire web metrics gathering process.

I've gotten access to the raw server logs, but it seems redundant to parse that given that they are already being processed by WebTrends.

To me it seems very scriptable, but how would I go about doing that? Is screen-scraping an option?

Answer (score 0):

I use ODBC for querying metrics and numbers out of webtrends. We even fill a scorecard with all key performance metrics..

Its in German, but maybe the idea helps you: http://www.web-scorecard.net/

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Which version of WebTrends are you using? Unless this is a very old install, there should be options to schedule these reports to be emailed to you, and also to bookmark queries. Let me know which version it is and I can make some recommendations.